# How can I place a text in tabBar and how can I know in which scene am I in storyboard, Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk, scene, corona-storyboard

I am using Corona SDK and I am facing a problem. In my Tab Bar Application, I need to know in which scene I am in order to change my text's text to the number of the scene. For example, if I am at "scene 1" I want my text's text to be "1", else if I am at "scene 2" I want my text's text to be "2".I aslo need to place my text in the tabBar.

I am thinking of doing somthing like

```
 local sceneName = (my scene's name)

 If sceneName == "Scene 1" then
     myText.text = "Scene 1"
 else if sceneName == "Scene 2" then
     myText.text = "Scene 2
```

So how can I place my text in the tabBar and how can I know my Scene's name?

Also how can I name a scene and how do I use it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [storyboard.getCurrentSceneName()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/legacy/api/library/storyboard/getCurrentSceneName.html) to get the name of the current scene. The name of the scene is the name of the lua file (without the `.lua` extension) that contains the scene code, i.e. the same name you use in [storyboard.gotoScene("mySceneName")](http://docs.coronalabs.com/legacy/api/library/storyboard/gotoScene.html).

If you want to have a scene where the name is not related to the lua file I think you have to use [storyboard.newScene("sceneName")](http://docs.coronalabs.com/legacy/api/library/storyboard/newScene.html) to create a new scene.